# Strange Area 51 community ad

Tags: bug, site-ads

I was navigating around and an ad popped up for the [Steem Area 51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121369/steem). I was curious what that was all about (I wasn't aware Area 51 proposals ran ads), but upon clicking the ad I was taken to

```
https://stackoverflow.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Farea51.stackexchange.com%2Fproposals%2F121369%2Fsteem%3Fcommit%3D1%26utm_medium%3Dad%26utm_source%3D%26utm_campaign%3D-area51-promo
```

Which... just loads the SO front page. Was this some sort of demo? A typo? I've not been able to get the ad to load again

Comment: I want to say I've seen this with an Area 51 ad before but I cannot find the old discussion (it would have been ages ago).

Comment: I tried to dig around for one but came up empty. let me know if you find it

Comment: How do we know that this meta post is not an ad for the Steem Area 51 proposal?

Comment: That proposal and its "committers" look rather suss.  A lot of committers have rep 51 (precisely) and most seem to have been referred by just one or two people.   (OTOH, if the committers are not genuine that is not a good sign for the long-term survival of the proposed site.)

Comment: @StephenC, Unfortunately most of the recent blockchain/cryptocurrency proposals have the same issues. Not to mention that a recent proposal was boosted by users from the same company.